# Rails 5 rspec - convert object to ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have method that use `.ids` for ActiveRecord array. Something like that:

```
def exmpale(array)
  method2(array.ids)
end
```

Now I want to create tests for this method, but when I create objects by FactoryBot I dont get ActiveRecord array. For example:

```
let(:array) { FactoryBot.create(:class_example) }
```

I can use `ClassExample.where` to get have ActiveRecord Relation, but Im not sure it's good idea. Is there any other soultion without changing method?

Comment: Why not send the `ids` as a parameter to `exmpale` method?

Comment: Beacuse Im doing some operation on array in `example` method. I didn't write it in this example. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to do it is to use `create_list` and return an `ActiveRecord` relation, but if I were you I'd rethink it to use `stubs`.

```
let(:array) do
  list = create_list(:class_example, 4)
  ClassExample.where(id: list.map(&:id))
end
```

Comment: I will try to learn how to use `stubs`, because Im not sure I want to use `where` in tests.

Comment: You are not using where in tests, that's just to return a ActiveRecord relation. If you don't want to use `where`, change your code to work with arrays instead of Relation. There are other alternatives, you just need to find them.

Comment: @N0ne Please add the unit test and the method you want to test. Maybe we can refactor.

Comment: I used your proposition. Thanks! ;)